# Connect both Cinema Display and Thunderbolt Display to a 15" Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display, cinema-display

Here's what I have:

- 2011 15" Macbook Pro (with Thunderbolt)
- 27" Apple Thunderbolt Display
- 27" Apple Cinema Display

From what I've [read](http://forums.appleinsider.com/t/132281/apple-clarifies-thunderbolt-display-will-not-daisy-chain-cinema-display), I cannot connect both displays by daisy chaining:

```
MacBook Pro -> Thunderbolt Display -> Cinema Display
```

What are my options for connecting both displays to a 15" Macbook Pro?

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read, the inability to connect a mini DisplayPort device to an Apple Thunderbolt Display is because of a bug in the Apple Thunderbolt Display. If you connect another device in between the Thunderbolt Display and the Cinema Display, they both should work along with your MacBook Pro's internal screen.

Comment: Yes, I've read about running through another non-display device. I wonder what the cheapest Thunderbolt pass-through peripheral is. http://www.macworld.com/article/1162365/first_look_apple_thunderbolt_display.html

Comment: Do you know if this still applies for the current generation of Apple Thunderbolt Displays?

Comment: @WavyCrab did you find something? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the same issue.

MacBokPro 15" 2019 -> Apple TB3/TB2 Adapter -> Thunderbolt Display -> Belkin Thunderbolt Express Dock (TB1), Model # F4U055 -> Cinema Display

After research the cheapest solution I found was to use a Thunderbolt 1 dock in between the Tunderbolt Display and the Cinema Display, I paid 70€ for a used one.